# Как подключить MS SQL к Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании скрипта в Юнити, а потом загрузке в VS Когда пытаюсь подключить библиотеки System.Data.Sql, то он почему то не видит их. Нужны ли какие-нибудь плагины или что-то подобное? При работе в консоли или на формах эти библиотеки спокойно подключаются. Это особенность Юнити или я что-то не то делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особенность Unity в том, что он каждый раз при перекомпиляции проекта он создаёт его файл заново. Условно, чего бы вы не задали в настройках проекта вижуалки - всё сбросится при первой же перекомпиляции.

Все библиотеки нужно подключать напрямую через юнити, поместив либу в папку с ассетами и настроив её подключение через инспектор юнити.

Если подключение через редактор не получится, можно создать в папке с ассетами файл mcs.rsp и записать в него текстовым редактором что-то вроде:

```
-reference:Assets/Plugins/Managed/System.Data.dll
-reference:Assets/Plugins/Managed/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
```